# What about this limit?...

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $\left(x_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_1},\,x_n:=\dfrac{a^n+b^n}{a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}}$, where $a,\,b\in\mathbb{R}:a\neq-b$. Then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{a^n+b^n}{a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}}\right)
$$
is...?

Comment: What have you ?

Comment: Well, I don't really know what to do here, but I guess I have to make a discussion about the magnitude of $a$ compared to the magnitude of $b$, or idk.

Comment: consider the cases $$a\le b$$ and $$a>b$$

Comment: "is... [something you should try to find out before asking it here without context or description of your own attempts, in case you didn't succeed.]"

Comment: All of the proofs are excellent, I'll just say that the key point behind every proof is the fact that whenever $|a|>|b|$ we have that for large values of $n$, $|a|^n$ is **much** greater than $|b|^n$ and so $b^n$ may be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

WLOG, $|a|\ge|b|$, so that the powers of $a$ dominate and the limit is that of $\dfrac{a^n}{a^{n+1}}=\dfrac1a$.

(Caution, when $a=b$, $a^n$ does not dominate but the limit is still $\dfrac1a$.)

Answer (score 0):

Limit expression can be rewritten as follows, considering the **case** $|b| < |a|$:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1+\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^n}{a+b\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^n}$$

Thus for this case the limit is $\frac{1}{a}$ since $\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

From here it follows that the sought limit is :

- $\frac{1}{a}$ if $|a| > |b|$
- $\frac{1}{b}$ if $|a| < |b|$
- $\frac{1}{a}$ if $a = b$

Comment: Not exactly. Take $a=-1,b=0$.

Comment: I cannot understand how to sum it up...

Comment: You are very close. But there's a missing case...

Comment: Thanks yves daoust!